# How to pass '#' without encoding it to WCF service?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service and I'm having an issue while passing a query string with '#' in (_password=...#) this makes the request ignoring the rest of the URL.

I have tried to Rewrite URL Rule but still the same

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="rule1">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="(.*)#(.*)" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}%23{C:2}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

I have also added

```
<system.net>
<settings>
  <httpListener unescapeRequestUrl="false"/>
</settings>
```

```
<uri>
<schemeSettings>
  <add name="http" genericUriParserOptions="DontUnescapePathDotsAndSlashes"/>
  <add name="https" genericUriParserOptions="DontUnescapePathDotsAndSlashes"/>
</schemeSettings>
```

```
<system.web>   
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
<httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="" requestValidationMode="2.0"/> 
<pages validateRequest="false" controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0"/>
```

But the issue is still remain.

Answer (score 1):

The short and simple answer:

You shouldn't, you don't, and you likely can't.

Every web oriented language has an encode and decode url method for good reason. One reason is reserved characters like `#` that would potentially break the internet if not used consistently.

So you should always encode and decode URI / URL and querystrings.

Secondly, it looks like you are worried about your password characters. As long as you are using Url Decode, it shouldn't matter at all!

example code might look like:

```
bool validCredentials(string uName, string pWord)
{
    var user = GetUser(uName);
    return uName == user.Name && pWord = server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["password"]);
}
```

Lastly, and not directly related: You shouldn't pass a password in a URL / Query... ever.It's one of the easiest bits of traffic to sniff and intercept as a "bad guy". By doing this you are basically throwing away free security.